# Rueidis (Redis) transaction using DoMulti

Tags: go, redis, rueidis

The given example in the README is as follows (modified very slightly to return err)

```
client.Dedicated(func(c rueidis.DedicatedClient) error {
    // watch keys first
    c.Do(ctx, c.B().Watch().Key("k1", "k2").Build())
    // perform read here
    c.Do(ctx, c.B().Mget().Key("k1", "k2").Build())
    // perform write with MULTI EXEC
    _, err := c.DoMulti(
        ctx,
        c.B().Multi().Build(),
        c.B().Set().Key("k1").Value("1").Build(),
        c.B().Set().Key("k2").Value("2").Build(),
        c.B().Exec().Build(),
    ).ToAny()
    return err
})
```

I only have a single `Set()` to perform but I'm unclear if I must pass my one `Set()` as param to `DoMulti()` to benefit from the CAS style transaction or if this example is just showing us how to (optionally) perform multiple `Set()` within a CAS transaction.

I have one `Set()` to perform but it is conditional on the watched key not changing. Would the following suffice? Would this `Set()` fail and return an appropriate error if the watched key value changes or expires?

```
client.Dedicated(func(c rueidis.DedicatedClient) error {
    // watch keys first
    c.Do(ctx, c.B().Watch().Key("k1").Build())
    // perform read here
    c.Do(ctx, c.B().Get().Key("k1").Build())
    // perform single write
    _, err := c.Do(ctx, c.B().Set().Key("k1").Value("1").Build()).ToAny()

    return err
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `rueian` at the rueidis project (https://github.com/redis/rueidis/discussions/494)

> If you rely on the WATCH, then you there are two must:
>
> 1. Using the WATCH in a dedicated connection. Modifying watched keys in a
> 2. MULTI EXEC block in the same connection.
>
> DoMulti is not required, but generally recommended.

Props to `rueian` for taking time out to help with my n00b question :)